# Spring MongoDb Update nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-mongodb

Hello I would like use this mongo query in spring to change type fields from string to double:

```
db.getCollection("data").update(
    {
        "location.latitude": { $type: 2 },
        "location.longitude": { $type: 2 }
    },
    [{
        $set: {
            "location.latitude": { $toDouble: "$geolocation.latitude" },
            "location.longitude": { $toDouble: "$geolocation.longitude" }
        }
    }]
)
```

Model:

```
data class Data(
    @Id
    val id: ObjectId,
    val location: Location,
)
```

My code in spring:

```
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(
            Query()
                .addCriteria(Criteria.where("data.latitude").`is`("\$type:2"))
                .addCriteria(Criteria.where("data.longitude").`is`("\$type:2")),
            Update()
                .set("location.latitude", ConvertOperators.ToDouble.toDouble("\$location.latitude"))
                .set("location.longitude", ConvertOperators.ToDouble.toDouble("\$location.longitude")),
            "data"
        )
```

but its generate something like that:

```
db.getCollection("data").update(
    {
        "location.latitude": "$type:2",
        "location.longitude": "$type:2"
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "location.latitude": { "$toDouble": "$geolocation.latitude" },
            "location.longitude": { "$toDouble": "$geolocation.longitude" }
        }
    }
)
```

but its not correct

Comment: Not Spring developer. Think you need [`AggregationUpdate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationUpdate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `type` function in spring not `is` to check `type`

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#type-int-)

```
Criteria.where("data.latitude").type(2)
```

For the second problem, As @YongShun pointed out you need to use [AggregationUpdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationUpdate.html)

```
AggregationUpdate.update()
    .set("location.latitude", ConvertOperators.ToDouble.toDouble("\$location.latitude"))
    .set("location.longitude", ConvertOperators.ToDouble.toDouble("\$location.longitude"))
```

Comment: Ok, but I have next issue, after updated, record looks like:

"location" : {
        "latitude" : {
            "$toDouble" : "$location.latitude"
        }, 
        "longitude" : {
            "$toDouble" : "location.longitude"
        }
    }
I think the problem is with square brackets, in spring query these brackets is missing

Comment: I got your problem. You need to use Aggregate Update.